# Does Blinding Speed trigger on use or on hit?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

The Blinding Speed rune for Dashing Strike adds the ability:

> Receive a 20% increased chance to Dodge for 3 seconds.

However, there is no status above my skill bar to show that this bonus is active.  When exactly am I getting this bonus?  Do I need to hit an enemy with the skill or simply use it?

Comment: Not all bonuses show up as buff icons.  Fists of Thunder also gives dodge, but I don't see an icon for it, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blinding Speed triggers **on hit** and does not have an icon to indicate that the buff is active.  To see this, open the details page of your character and Dash into any convenient enemy.  If your dodge is already high, you wont see much of an increase, but if you strip down to your skivvies, all will be revealed.

Additionally, Blinding Speed **will not** trigger when used on a destructible piece of the environment.

Comment: Any hope for some science on where the diminishing returns start/stop?

Comment: @RavenDreamer - I could only devote 1 hour to science at the time.  I'll need a bit more.

Comment: Just to add, the bonus activates on every 3rd combo hit (the hit that creates the lightning sphere in front of you.

Comment: @SergeantMad - This is about the Dashing Strike Rune, not Fists of Thunder

Comment: Indeed it is, sorry, my bad.